# Extract data from multiple rows table in MS Access user form using VBA

Tags: vba, user-interface, ms-access-2007

I have linked table from SQL and I am extracting top two rows into temporary table. I need to publish results from both rows into my user form. How can I extract data to my user form from the second row?

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Inputs")
        If rs.EOF = False Then
        Me.txt_date_1.Value = rs!period_end_dt.Value
        Me.txt_date)_2.Value = rs!period_end_dt.(row, 2).Value
        End If
```

Comment: Move next is what you need to do, recordset, a set of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rs.MoveNext` to go to the second record

```
Me.txt_date_1.Value = rs!period_end_dt.Value
rs.MoveNext
Me.txt_date_2.Value = rs!period_end_dt.Value
```